# React.UseContext, useContext hook usage

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm new to react and I have a question about optimising the code in the project.
It seems that the React.UseContext or useContext hook is suitable for my case, but I don't fully understand the syntax/approach with this hook.

My project is slowly starting to grow and some function or variables have to be dragged across 3 or more components just to use it in one place:

## App.js

```
const [costs, setCosts] = useState(null);
const deleteCostHandler = (itemId) => {
    setCosts((prevCosts) => {
      let res = prevCosts.filter((cost) => cost.id !== itemId);
      return [...res];
    });
  };
//jsx..
 <ConstContext.Provider><Cost value={{deleteCostHandler}} /></ConstContext.Provider>
```

## Cost.js

```
const costDeleteHandler = (incomeId) => {
    props.dataDelete(incomeId);
};
 <CostList costDelete={costDeleteHandler} />
```

## CostList.js

```
const passDataForUpdateHandler = (deletedId) => {
    props.costDelete(deletedId);
};
<CostItem refreshAfterDelete={passDataForUpdateHandler} />
```

And finaly..

## CostItem.js

```
const onDeleteHandler = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/costs/" + props.id, {
      method: "DELETE",
    }).then(() => {
      props.refreshAfterDelete(props.id);
      props.clearInputs(true);
    });
  };
 <button type="button" onClick={onDeleteHandler}>
```

I tried to create ConstContext.js file and store the needed functionality to cut the code and use it like:
ctx.deleteCostHandler(props.id);, but i get error 'deleteCostHandler is not a function', so I'm clearly doing something wrong.
I would be grateful if someone could explain/direct me to the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are not *providing* the context anywhere in your app's component tree. At someplace, usually somewhere above the components that need to consume the context, you add the Provider component exposed on the context object itself.

Take a look at the [React documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context#step-3-provide-the-context) on this.

Edit: You are not consuming it anywhere either. Please provide an example of the code that produces the error you mentioned in the question.

Comment: I understand that, I made a rollback, to the last working state.
In my Case it should be in App.js 
<ConstContext.Provider><Cost value={{deleteCostHandler}} /></ConstContext.Provider>
and than used in CostItem ctx.deleteCostHandler(props.id);

Comment: I guess it was mistake with function name that I passed earlier in CostItem component, everything works now, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Found error, wrong function name passed in Cost.js component.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).